# Cut and past excel file in vba

Tags: excel, vba

With the below code, I am able to create a copy of excel but I want to move the particular file from one location to another location. Please advise as to what all changes are require in below code.

```
myFileNameDir = Sheet1.Range("V4").Value & TextBox38.Text & ".xlsx"
Workbooks.Open Filename:=myFileNameDir, UpdateLinks:=0
Set ws1 = Worksheets("sheet1")
ws1.Activate
ws1.SaveAs Sheet1.Range("V3").Value & TextBox3.Text & ".xlsx"
```

Comment: Most ridiculous approved edit ever!!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ws1.SaveAs "C:\yourpath\" & Sheet1.Range("V3").Value & TextBox3.Text & ".xlsm"
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will move your file without having to open it:

```
Sub test()

Dim mySourceFileName As String
Dim myTargetFileName As String

mySourceFileName = Sheet1.Range("V4").Value & TextBox38.Text & ".xlsx"
myTargetFileName = Sheet1.Range("V3").Value & TextBox3.Text & ".xlsx"

MsgBox "File Copied:" & CopyFile(mySourceFileName, myTargetFileName, True), vbOKOnly

End Sub

Function CopyFile(FromFile As String, ToFile As String, Overwrite As Boolean) As Boolean

    Dim oFSO As Object
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    On Error Resume Next
    oFSO.CopyFile FromFile, ToFile, Overwrite
    CopyFile = (Err.Number = 0)
    Err.Clear

End Function
```

To move the file use:

```
Sub test()

Dim mySourceFileName As String
Dim myTargetFileName As String

mySourceFileName = Sheet1.Range("V4").Value & TextBox38.Text & ".xlsx"
myTargetFileName = Sheet1.Range("V3").Value & TextBox3.Text & ".xlsx"

MsgBox "File Moved:" & MoveFile(mySourceFileName, myTargetFileName), vbOKOnly

End Sub

Public Function MoveFile(FromFile As String, ToFile As String) As Boolean

    Dim oFSO As Object
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    On Error Resume Next
    oFSO.MoveFile FromFile, ToFile
    MoveFile = (Err.Number = 0)
    Err.Clear

End Function
```

Comment: I changed the oFSO.CopyFile to oFSO.MoveFile  but it is not working. It is showing as File copied = false and not moving the file to another folder

Comment: Apologies, remove the `Overwrite` arguments.  I'll add that to my answer.